# How to use the idiom "stop by" with a pronoun?

Tags: phrase-usage, usage

I know the meaning of the idiom "**stop by**" (come over for a short visit) but I don't know to use the idiom "stop by" with a pronoun.

For example, can I say "I'm going to stop by **him**", or "Please, come to stop by **me**" or "He went to stop by **her**"?

According to [this site](http://www.use-in-a-sentence.com/a-words/collocation-2/stop-by.htm) (which contains a lot of example of uses) I suspect that I have to use the preposition "with" since it states:

> Sam may stop by **with** Peter and Ted, and Roger Ailes wants to talk
>   about this idea for a legal show that .

Comment: I've never heard of the "use-in-a-sentence" website, but almost any dictionary defines the phrasal verb _stop by._ For instance, [**Collins**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stop-by), [**Free Dictionary**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/stop+by), and [**Oxford Learner's**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/stop-by). We _stop by_ a location, not a person. Example: "Let's _stop by_ Dave's house." "We can _stop by_ the tailor on our way to Dave's."

Comment: In your example the meaning is "Sam may stop by (some place) with Peter and Ted...". *stop by* relates to *some place* (the object of the action), not *with Peter and Ted* (the participants).

Answer (score 2):

If *by* takes an explicit object it designates a place, not a person: "I'll stop by your office and pick up the file."

If *by* does not have an object, the place is assumed to be a place named earlier, or the place where your hearer is now, or will be found.

The *with* phrase in the sentence you quote is not part of the *stop by* construction. It's an adjunct naming the people who will accompany Sam—they will come *with* him.

Comment: After cogitating on it a bit, it occurs to me that we do hear _by [person]_ in NAmE colloquial speech. _"Hey, let's go by Dave"_ and _stop by [name]_ would not sound out of place; oddly, though, _stop by [pronoun]_ would.

Comment: I would expect ""Hey, let's go/stop by Dave's (place)", but not using *Dave*. (AmE)

Comment: In my neck of the woods we would say *Let's stop by at Dave's ...* to refer to Dave's house or apartment.   But if the proper name was the name of a bar or restaurant, say, then it could stand in for a place and complement **by**, as StoneyB has stated.  *Let's stop by Sadie's* (a corner-store when I was a kid).

Comment: @TRomano Quite so. If *by* acts as a transitive preposition and takes an object, a nominal, that object is one which designates a place, and *by X* is a locative PP; if there's not an object, *by* is an intransitive preposition (in effect, a P which acts by itself as a PP) which may be further specified by 'stacking' an ordinary PP like "at your place" or "to Sadie's".